# Magento 2 Curl Rest Endpoints

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl

I'm trying to access the REST Endpoints:

```
POST /V1/products/special-price
POST /V1/products/special-price-information
POST /V1/products/special-price-delete
```

I want to achieve this through PHP code however i'm finding it hard to understand just how to access them. I want to be able to GET the special prices of specific products. Any direction would be a help.

Comment: you can get special price like https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$url="http://localhost/magento/index.php/";
$tokenUrl=$url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$productSpecialUrl=$url. "rest/V1/products/special-price";
$username="admin";
$password="password";


//get admin access token
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$dataString = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init($tokenUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$requestPayload = json_encode(array(array('price' => 100, 'store_id' => 1, 'sku' => 'sku123', 'price_from' => date, 'price_to' => date )));
$ch = curl_init($productSpecialUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestPayload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Let me know if you need further help.